# Are ellipsoid and datum the same?

Tags: coordinate-system, datum, gis-principle, ellipsoid

Are the **datum** and the **ellipsoid** the same? What is a Datum?

> The Earth is shaped like a flattened sphere. This shape is called an
>   ellipsoid. A datum is a model of the earth that is used in mapping.
>   The datum consists of a series of numbers that define the shape and
>   size of the ellipsoid and it's orientation in space. A datum is chosen
>   to give the best possible fit to the true shape of the Earth.  in this
>   article....

Comment: Please refer to this Q&A to get a response (or at least part of it) : http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/664/whats-the-difference-between-a-projection-and-a-datum

Comment: It might also help if you can tell us what research you've already done.

Comment: actually this is not a duplication. he asked about ellipsoid-vs-datum and the Q you refer to is projection-vs-datum. the answer is: ellipsoid is a 3d mathematical surface. a datum consists of an ellipsoid + more parameters. for example the same ellipsoid can be set at different positions and orientations and then you'l have different datums

Comment: For some reason I was unable to re-open this question when I tried to just now.  In any event, I think it is a duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/175293/difference-between-datum-and-ellipsoid-for-geodetic-coordinates instead of the Q&A to which it is currently assigned.