# What is a coordinate system?

Tags: coordinate-system

Please help me understand a coordinate system and how a coordinate system is relevant to a region of interest such as South Africa. I came across this term a couple of times and overlooked it because I don't really know what it refers to.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_reference_system

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the difference between a projection and a datum?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/664/whats-the-difference-between-a-projection-and-a-datum)

Comment: Not the clearest but may give you keywords that you can search for: http://www.ngi.gov.za/index.php/technical-information/geodesy-and-gps/datum-s-and-coordinate-systems

Comment: Are you asking "What is a coordinate system?" or are you asking "What is/are the coordinate systems used in South Africa?"

Be specific so you get an accurate answer.

Comment: This is such a good question it has been asked and answered many times on this site: search for [coordinate system](http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%22coordinate%20system%22).

Comment: In my opinion, this is a valid question.  Often newcomers to geography/GIS are confused by the complementary terms "coordinate system", "projection", "spatial reference", "datum", etc...

Comment: This question is more specific now, after editing by @Aaron, previously it was ambiguous. I agree with the sentiment of Aaron. Terminology is key and there are lots of resources here on stack as well on ESRI.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree that this question should be left open because it would be useful to find (if it gets enough votes) in our most [frequently asked questions on Coordinate Systems](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coordinate-system?sort=frequent).

Comment: Thanks Aaron for the edits, spk578 I'm actually asking for both and thanks to everybody for the prompt response on citations.

Comment: @ElDIX thanks for your reply I guess this thread should be left as What is a coordinate system? and you should ask another question for "What is/are the coordinate systems used in South Africa?"

Comment: @EIDIX I've gone ahead and ask the question for you and added an answer...http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/152751/what-is-are-the-coordinate-systems-used-in-south-africa please feel free to continue the comments and questions on SA CRS's there.

Answer (score 2):

A good starting place for GIS terminology is the [GIS Dictionary](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/GISDictionary/term/coordinate%20system) hosted by Esri.

**Coordinate System**

> A reference framework consisting of a set of points, lines, and/or
>   surfaces, and a set of rules, used to define the positions of points
>   in space in either two or three dimensions. The Cartesian coordinate
>   system and the geographic coordinate system used on the earth's
>   surface are common examples of coordinate systems.

[image]

Comment: For new users (generally already overwhelmed by new concepts) I usually 'dumb it down' to "A coordinate system is instructions that programs understand about placing the coordinates in *what* units and from *what* starting point. After all the world is *round* so you have to start *somewhere*.". Later on, after they've got familiar with the basics, I go into which ones to use and which ones 'play nice' with each other.