# Do i need to list projection on map when using wgs84

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I have been creating maps using project `CRS:WGS84` or `ESPG:4326` when I export these maps (with grids listing the coordinates and suffix) I have just been writing on the map `CRS:WGS84`. Should I be writing the projection as well?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] where you will see that there should be only one question asked per question under our focussed Q&A format.  Here you seem to be asking two questions.  The first seems to be asking about a cartographic/GIS principle while the second is about the QGIS software.  Please decide which question you wish to ask about in this particular question and use the [edit] button to revise it accordingly.  The other question can always be researched/asked separately.

Comment: Read https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/664/29005 to learn about the difference between CRS and projections.

In short: Yes, you absolutely should give information about the projection. Projection always are to linked to a datum, so every reader will be able to figure that one out easily. But without knowing the projection, it will be hard to make your data usable with other data that might be in other projections.

Comment: It's not in a "true" map projection. The decimal degree values are being treated as if they are linear units. Some people call this pseudo-plate carree. True plate carree scales the values into linear units.