# Reprojecting raster file with unknown datum using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, coordinate-system, arcmap, grib

[image]I am new to GIS. I had a grib format data file and it's coordinate system shown below. I want to project it to WGS84, however, the datum of original file is unknown. I know I need to provide the datum info while projecting.

How can I solve this using ArcGIS Desktop?

[image]

Comment: You have to declare the output datum. There is a WGS 84 datum you can use. See [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/664/whats-the-difference-between-a-projection-and-a-datum) for more info on projections and datums

Comment: You can reproject it, but it might be dozens of kilometers in error.  In general, without other information to attempt proper registration, *unknown datum* means *unusable data*.

Comment: If you add the raster to ArcMap and look at the data frame properties, coordinate system tab, can you get the spheroid (ellipsoid) information? That may or may not help us give you an answer.

Comment: Also where did you get the data / who's the data provider? Do they talk about coordinate systems at all?